# How to extract a single element from webpage?

Tags: python, macos, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am looking to extract a single value as text from the following webpage.

[Cascade River Rustic Campground](https://www.fs.usda.gov/recarea/superior/recreation/camping-cabins/recarea/?recid=36913&actid=29)

Specifically, I'm after the "4" value after the "No. of Sites" text (see screenshot)

[image]

I've been able to isolate the xpath using Chrome, which is as follows:

```
//*[@id="act_1"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]
```

The following code yields an empty list:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url = "https://www.fs.usda.gov/recarea/superior/recreation/camping-cabins/recarea/?recid=36913&actid=29"

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
x = tree.xpath('//*[@id="act_1"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
print x
```

The expected output should be:

```
>>> print x
['4']
```

How can I extract a single element (i.e. "4") in a web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this *xpath* works for me (note there's no *tbody*) and use `text()` to extract the text from a node:

```
x = tree.xpath('//*[@id="act_1"]/div[1]/table/tr/td[2]/text()')

print(x[0].strip())
# 4
```